# SQLite in PhoneGap iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, sqlite, html, cordova

I'm trying to use SQLite in phonegap for iPhone, I'm facing the following problem, Please have a look at the below javascript code.
Thanks a lot

```
function testAsSeperateFunctionDB(contact)
{
  database.transaction(
    function( transaction ){
      alert("enteringIntoTransaction");
      transaction.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO testTableThree (contactId, mrMrs, firstName, 
           lastName, jobTitle, bActive, homePhone, contactType, accountId, 
           workPhone, cellularPhone, workFax, contactEmail, owner, 
           alternateCountry, alternateAddress1, alternateAddress2, 
           alternateZipCode, alternateCity, alternateProvince) 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);',

        [contact.contactId, contact.mrMrs,
        contact.firstName, contact.lastName,
        contact.jobTitle, contact.bActive,
        contact.homePhone, contact.contactType,
        contact.accountId, contact.workPhone,
        contact.cellularPhone, contact.workFax,
        contact.contactEmail, contact.owner,
        contact.alternateCountry, contact.alternateAddress1,
        contact.alternateAddress2, contact.alternateZipCode,
        contact.alternateCity, contact.alternateProvince],

        //Callback after successful transaction
        function( transaction, results ) {
          alert("added");
        },

        //Callback after error in transaction 
        function( transaction, error ) {
          alert("Error" + error.code);
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

I'm using the above function to add a set of contact details into a table, I will be passing a JSON object to this function. I'm calling the above function in the following loop structure.

```
for(i = 0; i < contactFullObjArray.length; i++) {
  //Parse the ContactFull object
  var contact=ContactFull.parse(contactFullObjArray[i]);    
  testAsSeperateFunctionDB(contact);        
}
```

What's happening here is transaction is happening only after the whole for loop is executed, and it is getting called only once, which makes only the final values that are passed to be added into the table. (I'm getting the alert "enteringIntoTransaction" only once, and that value is getting added into the database. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by placing the

transaction.executeSql()

inside the for loop and iterated through it.